Optimize Ansible task to restart windows task scheduler on configured times
I have the following simple scheduler restart task for Windows and it works just fine, however I would like to have the option of maybe sometimes setting restart_morning_time or restart_evening_time to NULL. What's the cleanest way to go about this? I tried having it as a list and also comma separated so I can pass as many restart_times as I want and instead of having 2 variables, I would just have one called restart_times (this would be ideal) but that just gives an error:

fatal: [windows-test-1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "trigger
option 'start_boundary' must be in the format 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss'
format but was '2024-08-10T07:00:00 2024-08-10T19:00:00'"}

- name: Schedule restart for windows machine 
  community.windows.win_scheduled_task:
    name: "Scheduled restart machine"
    description: "This task restarts the machine at configured date && time"
    actions:
      - path: shutdown.exe
        arguments: "/r /f /t 0"
    triggers:
      - type: "{{ trigger_type }}"
        start_boundary: "{{ restart_morning_time }}"
      - type: "{{ trigger_type }}"
        start_boundary: "{{ restart_evening_time }}"
    username: "SYSTEM"
    run_level: highest
    state: present

These are my vars I'm passing:
vars:
  trigger_type: "daily"  # Options could be 'daily', 'weekly', 'monthly'
  restart_morning_time: "2024-08-10T07:00:00"
  restart_evening_time: "2024-08-10T19:00:00"


One work around I have found for this is to add default(omit) to the triggers but if there are better ways I'm open to suggestions;
triggers:
  - type: "{{ trigger_type }}"
    start_boundary: "{{ restart_morning_time | default(omit) }}"
  - type: "{{ trigger_type }}"
    start_boundary: "{{ restart_evening_time | default(omit) }}"

